# Property name of a structure to string

Tags: go

I would like to know if it is possible to get the name of a property from a structure and convert it to string.

For example in the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type StructA struct {
    ValueAA string
    ValueAB string
}

type StructB struct {
    ValueBA    string
    ValueBB    string
    RefStructA StructA
}

func main() {
    //pass any attribute of any structure
    fmt.Println(castProperty(StructB.RefStructA.ValueAA))
    //print the name passed but in string. Do not print the value
    //expected output: "StructB.RefStructA.ValueAA"
}

func castProperty(value interface{}) string {
    //some code
}
```

Is it possible to write a function that allows obtaining the name of the property of a structure and converted to a string? property value is not required.

Answer (score 1):

That's called `Reflection`. I let you read the page, it lets you do what you want.

First, read the *The first law of reflection*: https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var x float64 = 3.4
    fmt.Println("type:", reflect.TypeOf(x))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/OuGgD1TlSMO

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly how do you want to give input to your function but here is an example that may help you

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    getPropertyName(B{})
}

type A struct {
    field1 string
}

type B struct {
    field A
}

func getPropertyName(b interface{}) {
    parentType := reflect.TypeOf(b)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(b)

    for i := 0; i< val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
        t := val.Type().Field(i)
        ty := val.Type().Field(i).Type.Name()
        log.Println(parentType.Name()+"."+ t.Name+"."+ty)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type StructA struct {
    ValueAA string
    ValueAB string
}

type StructB struct {
    ValueBA    string
    ValueBB    string
    RefStructA StructA
}

func main() {
    x := &StructB{RefStructA: StructA{ValueAA: "something"}}
    fmt.Printf("%+v", x)
}
```

out :

```
&{ValueBA: ValueBB: RefStructA:{ValueAA:something ValueAB:}}
```